# How can I retrieve the query definition (SQL text) of an Access query and store back a changed definition

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-schema, ddl

I have a requirement where I need to read queries from Access DB in c# and check if the access db query has any keyword like "KEY" if it has keywords  I need to enclose that in square brackets"[]".just like how it is done in SQL.

Could someone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `Read queries`? Are you checking every table if they contain a keyword, or one table? Please clarify your question.

Comment: In MDB file we have few queries. I want to read those queries and create similar queries in sql. say we have a query in access db like this.

Comment: select KEY from Table1;                                                   since KEY is a keyword in sql..I want to read this query from access and create one in SQL like this Select [KEY] from Table1.

Comment: since SQL does not compile queries with keyword, I want to enclose them in square brackets after reading it from access db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve the query text like this:

```
string connString =  @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\...\myDB.mdb";
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString )) {
    conn.Open();
    string[] restrictions = new string[] { null, null, "myQuery" };
    DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("Views", restrictions);
    if (schema.Rows.Count > 0) {
        DataRow row = schema.Rows[0];
        string queryText = (string)row["VIEW_DEFINITION"];
        Console.WriteLine(queryText);
    }
}
```

If you drop the restrictions argument with the query name, `conn.GetSchema("Views")` returns one row for each query. If you query `conn.GetSchema("Procedures")` other types of queries like insert, update and DDL statements that are not considered as queries are returned in `row["PROCEDURE_DEFINITION"]`.

View (query) names are returned in `row["TABLE_NAME"]` and procedure names in `row["PROCEDURE_NAME"]`.

---

And you can update the query like this:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connString)) {
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand("DROP PROCEDURE myQuery", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd = new OleDbCommand("CREATE PROCEDURE myQuery AS SELECT * FROM myTable", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Strangely enough the OleDb CREATE DDL (Data Definition Language) designates the queries  as 'procedures' but the schema table returns a 'VIEW_DEFINITION' and the query name is returned in the column 'TABLE_NAME'. SELECT queries must be retrieved as "Views", other types of queries as "Procedures"; however, both types are created as PROCEDUREs.

Comment: Does not work when using ODBC Access driver: "Column 'VIEW_DEFINITION' does not belong to table Views."

Comment: @nh43de: Note that different databases implement these schema tables differently. Not all databases provide all the tables and the tables might have different sets of columns! And since the `GetSchema` method is a member of the connection, the connection type has an influence as well.

Loop through the `DataTable.Columns` and look how the columns are named.

Comment: These are the only columns available when using ODBC: 
    [0]: "TABLE_CAT"
    [1]: "TABLE_SCHEM"
    [2]: "TABLE_NAME"
    [3]: "TABLE_TYPE"
    [4]: "REMARKS". When using OLE there are more columns available, including "VIEW_DEFINITION"

Answer (score 2):

While I was testing the answer that @`Olivier Jacot-Descombes` provided, I was not able to retreive all the queries text representation. Therefore I applied some other method where you open the existing Ms Access database instance and read the queries that are stored in it.

Here is the class I used:

```
public class MsAccess
{
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access._Application _oAccess;

    public MsAccess(string path)
    {
        _oAccess = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access._Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(path);
    }

    public string ReturnSqlQueryText(string queryName)
    {
        string queryDef = null;
        var qdefs = _oAccess.CurrentDb().QueryDefs;

        foreach (QueryDef qdef in qdefs)
        {
            if(qdef.Name.Equals(queryName))
                queryDef = qdef.SQL;
        }

        return queryDef;
    }
}
```

Using this code might require you adding using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` both (15.0.0.0) where you can find them under `Extension` on the reference menu